# Not understanding F# syntax with type conversion

Tags: casting, f#

This works:

```
let a = 3
let b = string b
let c = a |> string
```

but:

```
let a = string j.SelectToken("hello")
```

doesn't work, while

```
let a = j.SelectToken("hello") |> string
```

works.

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler thinks you want to pass j.SelectToken to string. Remember, functions are values, so that is legal. Any of these work:

```
let a = j.SelectToken "hello" |> string
let a = string (j.SelectToken "hello")
let a = string <| j.SelectToken "hello"
let a = "hello" |> j.SelectToken |> string
```

Comment: That's where I fail to understand: the difference between string(x(y)) and string x(y); my understanding is that string is waiting for a parameter, and then (x(y)) or x(y) should be a single entity? I guess it's not but I don't understand how the parser is handling it

Comment: @Thomas string x(y) parses as (string x) (y)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you wrap `j.SelectToken("hello")` in parentheses, you get this error:

```
Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, 
and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized
F# Compiler(597)
```

Why has already been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23848236/5652483

There is an open issue with interesting discussion at https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/644